# Find pictures with several people together?

Tags: picasa

Is it possible to find pictures where several people are together?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Taken from [this Google Groups discussion](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/picasa/picasa-for-windows/D65yVjldUSM):

> Click on someone's people/face album.
>   You'll see thumbs for all the
>   photos that have that person in them.  Click the People" button, lower
>   right.  The People tab shows other people appearing in the same set of
>   photos.  Click on another person in the "People" tab.  That person
>   lights up blue.  And the number of displayed thumbnails shrinks to
>   only the photos with those two people.  Do a Ctrl-click on another
>   person... now you'll see only photos with all three people in them...